# Tycho Surefire cannot resolve Required Capabilities

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, tycho, tycho-surefire-plugin

We are building a huge set of eclipse bundles with many bundles being legacy.
Surefire Tests do not run and always fail with the error:

```
!SUBENTRY 2 com.my.plugin 2 0 2018-06-07 15:43:43.649
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osg
i.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))".
```

Other plugins are complaining about CDC/Foundation-1.0. The online help is not very useful regarding this matter. How can one force tycho to launch the proper osgi Execution Environments

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <showEclipseLog>true</showEclipseLog>
                    <useJDK>SYSTEM</useJDK>
                    <argLine>-Dorg.osgi.framework.system.capabilities='&quot;osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE"";version:List='1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8'&quot;</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

the only hint we've got right now was something like this, but even this is error-prone with the quotes and doesn't do the trick

Comment: which JDK version are you using to execute the tests?

Comment: 1.8.0_121-b13.

I am more, however leaning toward the idea that it is the eclipse equinox launcher thta is the problem